# How do I disable keyboard shortcuts?

Tags: shortcut-keys, keyboard

I must have accidentally activate some keyboard shortcut function because every time I press certain keys such as w,a,s,d they act as shortcuts to things. For example if I press f, the search function appears. How can I stop this so I can type these letters again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like your <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key got some problem . because as we know <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> for search and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> to select etc.